# Flutter webview_flutter build is failing

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to install webview_flutter plugin but somehow my build is failing every time

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...

Running Xcode build...

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          10.2s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         2.1s
Xcode build done.
17.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <path_to_project>ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal
    error: module 'webview_flutter' not found
    @import webview_flutter;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  webview_flutter: ^0.3.19+8
```

I tried running but it did not solve it.

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have the same issue with the most recent version of webview_flutter and all the recommended solutions fail.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I had manually edited the podfile to add in my own (non-flutter) pod to the project. However, the flutter build would make no attempt to edit (or overwrite) the podfile, (maybe this is good) so the podfile would not have the changes necessary to support webview_flutter. I figured this all out by creating a brand new flutter project and comparing the new project's generated podfile against my current version. They looked significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you follow **all the installation for iOS** for this plugin?

This is from the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) page itself:

> **To use this plugin on iOS you need** to opt-in for the embedded views
>   preview by adding a boolean property to the app's Info.plist file,
>   with the key io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and the value YES.

This also seems to be related, take a look: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50190

Comment: I followed it. If you look at the error, this is related to build xocde output.

Answer (score -1):

**flutter upgrade** solved problem for me